# Multiple Input Feature Classes with Different Names - Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have created the model below to create "straight lines" from a route (Feature Class is the Route in the model). This model will save me a lot of time compared to doing it manual. The manual steps are as follows: File> Add Data> Add Route Data... New window appears, the route and route identifier are already selected from my TOC, but all the other information must be entered then you hit ok.. route event is created, then the event must be exported to a gdb, added to the map, then symbolized. My issue here is, I would like for the model to recognize my feature class (the route) from within my TOC like the manual window does. I do not want to run my model and every time have to keep adding the route.

I have about 30 maps this model will be run off of. Each route has a different name. Would it be possible to give them an alias name such as "Route" and set the model's "Feature Class" to recognize that instead? So as long as in each different map the route is named "Route" the model will recognize that and I will not have to manually add the feature class (route). Not opposed to python.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are generating routes through linear referencing. All the available tools for linear referencing are discussed in the Help page titled [An overview of the Linear Referencing toolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-linear-referencing-toolbox.htm).

I sounds like you want to be using the Make Route Event Layer.

Comment: You are correct. That is the tool I am using in model builder. However, when I do "add route events" manually in my maps, the add route events window that appears recognizes the input route in my TOC, so I do not have to navigate to or drag and drop the input route. When I run my tool in the map, I would also like it to recognize the route in my TOC. Currently with my model, I have it set as a parameter and have to navigate to its location every time for every map. I would like it recognize that route input for every map.

Comment: If the route name is static then simple type it into the parameter when you are in modelbuilder.

Comment: It is not, but that crossed my mind. If all ~30 routes had an alias with one static name that could work. I think that is my best bet for now. Thanks!

Comment: So if I name all routes "Route" in the TOC and name my input route feature class "Route" it should recognize it in each map?

Comment: No. At this point I would recommend you edit your question to show the model you are trying to build.

Comment: Edited it and added model.

Comment: OK looking at your model you have exposed parameters which tells me you are running this as a tool from within ArcMap. I had assumed that your 30 routes were 30 layers IN A SINGLE MXD, but re-reading your question above they are different layers in different MXDs, if that is the case then YES, renaming them all to a single name (but in different MXDs) then your tool should just pick up on the layer name.

Comment: You can event set the parameter default value to be the layer name to avoid typing or selecting it.